# In a form <select> element, how do I use the onchange event handler to link directly to the chosen option?

Tags: widget, javascript, forms, text

This is what i've used in the past for non-wordpress sites:

```
function goThere() {
    var list = document.forms[0].articles
    location = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
}
```

**The select element that calls the function:**

```
<form>
<select id="articles" name="articles" onchange="goThere()">
 <option value="#" selected>Choose an article</option>
 <option value="document1.pdf">Document 1</option>
 <option value="document2.pdf">Document 2</option>
 <option value="document3.pdf">Document 3</option>
</form>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with WordPress?

Answer (score 5):

You are not closing your select tag.

You are not ending your javascript lines with semi-colons.

location is not an object, you need to use document.location.href.

Try this:

```
function goThere() {
    var list = document.getElementById('articles');
    document.location.href = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
}
```